# Definition of covariant derivative and geodesic on surfaces

Tags: derivatives, differential-geometry, geodesic

In the book "Elementary differential geometry" by Andrew Pressley. The author explained the definition of covariant derivative by saying that "an observer restricted to the surface of the Earth perceives only the component of the acceleration tangential to the surface". Why do we know that?

Comment: Good question. It’s not a great explanation. An observer on the earth does perceive the non tangential component of acceleration. The acceleration of a falling object is the simplest example.

Comment: If, however, you assume the earth is perfectly smooth and the object is always touching the ground, then the tangential component of acceleration is indeed the covariant derivative of velocity. If you assume that we had no perception of height above the earth and everything always touched the surface, then indeed we would be able to perceive only the tangential component of acceleration. I think this is what the author had in mind. But it’s a less elegant story.